# Update lines in master spreadsheet failing

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following code which is designed to update a master spreadsheet when I update job sheets with new details. The code fails to update the spreadsheet stating sub set out of range, I need to be able to modify the code for use in other folders using the same cell mappings.

```
Sub UpdateRow()

  '  Const FOLDER_NAME As String = "\\Albaserver2\my documents\ALBA REPORTS NOV 2017\IN\" '<===== change to suit
  '  Const strFolderA = "\\Albaserver2\my documents\ALBA REPORTS NOV 2017\IN\"
  '  Const strFolderB = "\\Albaserver2\my documents\ALBA REPORTS NOV 2017\"
    
    Const FOLDER_NAME As String = "U:\ALBA REPORTS NOV 2017\IN\" '<===== change to suit
    Const strFolderA = "U:\ALBA REPORTS NOV 2017\IN\"
    Const strFolderB = "U:\ALBA REPORTS NOV 2017\"
   
    
    
    Dim StartTime As Double, EndTime As Double
    Dim wbTo As Workbook, wbFrom As Workbook
    'Dim strFolderA As String
    'Dim strFolderB As String
    Dim NextFile As String
    Dim PathName As String
    Dim oSht As Worksheet
    Dim lastRow As Long, i As Long
    Dim strSearch As String
    Dim aCell As Range
    Dim strEng As String
    
    
    On Error GoTo Err
    StartTime = Timer

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    Set wbTo = ActiveWorkbook
    Set oSht = wbTo.Sheets("job sheet")
    NextFile = Dir(FOLDER_NAME & "*.xls", vbNormal)
    Do While NextFile <> ""
        Set wbFrom = Workbooks.Open(FOLDER_NAME & NextFile)
        lastRow = oSht.Range("G" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        strSearch = wbFrom.Sheets(1).Range("F3")
        Set aCell = oSht.Range("G1:G" & lastRow).Find(What:=strSearch, LookIn:=xlValues, _
        LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
        MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
        Set shtData = wbTo.Sheets("job sheet")
        If Not aCell Is Nothing Then
            shtData.Cells(aCell.Row, 1) = StrConv(wbFrom.Sheets(1).Range("B7"), vbProperCase) 'Property
            shtData.Cells(aCell.Row, 2) = StrConv(wbFrom.Sheets(1).Range("H7"), vbProperCase)  'Location
            shtData.Cells(aCell.Row, 3) = StrConv(wbFrom.Sheets(1).Range("B11"), vbProperCase) 'Work to be carried out
            shtData.Cells(aCell.Row, 4) = wbFrom.Sheets(1).Range("B3") 'Date
            shtData.Cells(aCell.Row, 5) = wbFrom.Sheets(1).Range("D3") 'Time In
            shtData.Cells(aCell.Row, 6) = wbFrom.Sheets(1).Range("J19") 'Time On Site
            shtData.Cells(aCell.Row, 8) = wbFrom.Sheets(1).Range("H3") 'Order Number
            shtData.Cells(aCell.Row, 9) = wbFrom.Sheets(1).Range("H4") 'Job Line
            shtData.Cells(aCell.Row, 10) = wbFrom.Sheets(1).Range("E9") 'Code
            shtData.Cells(aCell.Row, 11) = StrConv(wbFrom.Sheets(1).Range("F5"), vbUpperCase) 'Client
            'shtData.Cells(aCell.Row, 12) = Left(wbFrom.Sheets(1).Range("B5"), 1) & Mid$(wbFrom.Sheets(1).Range("B5"), InStr(wbFrom.Sheets(1).Range("B5"), " ") + 1, 1)
            shtData.Cells(aCell.Row, 12) = wbFrom.Sheets(1).Range("B5") 'Caller
            shtData.Cells(aCell.Row, 17) = wbFrom.Sheets(1).Range("F68") 'Invoice Amount
            strEng = wbFrom.Sheets(1).Range("G9")
            If Len(Trim(wbFrom.Sheets(1).Range("H9"))) <> 0 Then
                 strEng = strEng & "/" & wbFrom.Sheets(1).Range("H9")
            End If
            If Len(Trim(wbFrom.Sheets(1).Range("J9"))) <> 0 Then

                 strEng = strEng & "/" & wbFrom.Sheets(1).Range("J9")
            End If
            If Len(Trim(wbFrom.Sheets(1).Range("G10"))) <> 0 Then
                 strEng = strEng & "/" & wbFrom.Sheets(1).Range("G10")

            End If
            If Len(Trim(wbFrom.Sheets(1).Range("H10"))) <> 0 Then
                 strEng = strEng & "/" & wbFrom.Sheets(1).Range("H10")
                 
            End If
            If Len(Trim(wbFrom.Sheets(1).Range("J10"))) <> 0 Then
                 strEng = strEng & "/" & wbFrom.Sheets(1).Range("J10")
                 
            End If
            shtData.Cells(aCell.Row, 13) = Trim(strEng)
            'shtData.Cells(aCell.Row, 13) = wbFrom.Sheets(1).Range("G9") 'Engineer
            'shtData.Cells(aCell.Row, 13) = Left(wbFrom.Sheets(1).Range("G9"), 1) & Mid$(wbFrom.Sheets(1).Range("G9"), InStr(wbFrom.Sheets(1).Range("G9"), " ") + 1, 1)
            shtData.Cells(aCell.Row, 14) = wbFrom.Sheets(1).Range("A16") 'Sub Con
        End If
        wbFrom.Close True
        If Dir(strFolderB & NextFile) <> "" Then
           Kill (strFolderB & NextFile)
           Name strFolderA & NextFile As strFolderB & NextFile
        Else
           Name strFolderA & NextFile As strFolderB & NextFile
        End If
        NextFile = Dir(FOLDER_NAME & "*.xls", vbNormal)
        'NextFile = Dir
        'Kill ("\\Albaserver2\my documents\ALBA REPORTS 2013\" & strSearch & ".xls")
        
        'Name strFolderA & NextFile As strFolderB & NextFile
        'NextFile = Dir
        'Kill ("\\Albaserver2\my documents\ALBA REPORTS 2013\" & strSearch & ".xls")
    Loop
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
     EndTime = Timer
     MsgBox Format(EndTime - StartTime, "00.00") & " seconds"
     


Exit Sub
Err:
    MsgBox Err.Description

End Sub
```

I have tried amending the code to reflect new destinations, a new master job sheet was open and it fails to update the information as per the cells in the code.
The following code does the original copy to the job sheet and works as expected, what am I missing on the update rows code?

```
Sub INVERCLYDEComplete()

'Find the last used row in both sheets and copy and paste data below existing data.

Dim wsCopy As Worksheet
Dim wsDest As Worksheet
Dim lCopyLastRow As Long
Dim lDestLastRow As Long

'Set variables for copy and destination sheets
Set wsCopy = Workbooks("IVC NEW BLANK TEMPLATE.xlsm").Worksheets("LOGIN AND CALC SHEETS")
Set wsDest = Workbooks("INVERCLYDE JOB SHEET.xlsm").Worksheets("job sheet")



'1. Find last used row in the copy range based on data in column A
'lCopyLastRow = wsCopy.Cells(wsCopy.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

'2. Find first blank row in the destination range based on data in column A
'Offset property moves down 1 row
lDestLastRow = wsDest.Cells(wsDest.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row

'3. Copy & Paste Data
    wsDest.Range("A" & lDestLastRow).Value = wsCopy.Range("B7").Value

    wsDest.Range("B" & lDestLastRow).Value = wsCopy.Range("H7").Value

    wsDest.Range("C" & lDestLastRow).Value = wsCopy.Range("B11").Value

    wsDest.Range("D" & lDestLastRow).Value = wsCopy.Range("B3").Value

    wsDest.Range("E" & lDestLastRow).Value = wsCopy.Range("D3").Value

    wsDest.Range("F" & lDestLastRow).Value = wsCopy.Range("J19").Value

    wsDest.Range("G" & lDestLastRow).Value = wsCopy.Range("F3").Value

    wsDest.Range("H" & lDestLastRow).Value = wsCopy.Range("H3").Value

    wsDest.Range("I" & lDestLastRow).Value = wsCopy.Range("H4").Value

    wsDest.Range("J" & lDestLastRow).Value = wsCopy.Range("E9").Value

    wsDest.Range("K" & lDestLastRow).Value = wsCopy.Range("G5").Value

    wsDest.Range("L" & lDestLastRow).Value = wsCopy.Range("B5").Value

   wsDest.Range("M" & lDestLastRow).Value = wsCopy.Range("G9").Value

   wsDest.Range("N" & lDestLastRow).Value = wsCopy.Range("A16").Value

   wsDest.Range("O" & lDestLastRow).Value = wsCopy.Range("A71").Value

   wsDest.Range("P" & lDestLastRow).Value = wsCopy.Range("E71").Value

   wsDest.Range("Q" & lDestLastRow).Value = wsCopy.Range("J132").Value

   wsDest.Range("S" & lDestLastRow).Value = wsCopy.Range("H19").Value



End Sub
```

Any help would be much appreciated, as I have been trying to figure this out for a few days now and keep hitting the same issue where the update rows code fails to update the necessary criteria.

Comment: What is the exact error message and on which line does it occur?  I've never seen a "sub set out of range" error.  Comment out the error handler if you need to debug.

Comment: Hi Tim, I used the Eh: function and get a message stating Label Not Defined for the update rows script

Comment: What is the "Eh: function" ?